# Produce single item maps procedurally from nested map in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a nested map variable of account name and ID by OU, like:

```
variable "aws_accounts" {
  type = map(map(any))
  default = {
    first_ou = {
      first_account  = "111111111"
      second_account = "222222222"
    }
    second_ou = {
      third_account  = "333333333"
      fourth_account = "444444444"
    }
  }
}
```

This is great for passing a map of account_name to account_id as a sub-variable to do things by ou and the modules in question are constructed to accept a map input.

I would like to also render a local so that I can also reference single accounts but get a map value for them without having to maintain a separate list of variables, like

```
local.first_account = {
  first_account  = "111111111"
}

local.second_account = {
  second_account = "222222222"
}

local.third_account = {
  third_account = "33333333"
}
```

etc.

I have tried various techniques but without success:

I cannot work out how to refer to each map in the array iteratively- most documentation seems to be based on lists and when I try to do a `for_each` I get

```
The "each" object can be used only in "module" or "resource" blocks, and only when the "for_each" argument is set.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your example, it seems like you want to take your two-level map and turn it into a single-level map where the keys are the account names and the "OU names" are just discarded.

Here's one way to achieve that:

```
locals {
  account_ids = merge(values(var.aws_accounts)...)
}
```

This first uses [`values`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/values.html) to take the values from the top-level map, producing a list of maps.

It then uses [`merge`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/merge.html) to take all of the elements from each of the maps and combine them into a single new map. I used the `...` symbol to tell Terraform that it should treat each element of the list as a separate argument to `merge`, rather than just passing the whole list as a single argument.

After merging these together you could potentially split them apart again, creating a separate map each, using a `for` expression.

```
locals {
  account_maps = tomap({
    for k, id in local.account_ids :
    k => { (k) = id }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, whilst this is a more elegant solution than the zipmap offered previously, it's not quite what I am after. I would like to construct series of maps, each containing a single key-value pair, where the key is also the name of the map- as in the second code-formatted part of my initial question. I should like to refer to single accounts by name and return a map without having to put in `account_name` twice or risk mismatches due to human error

Comment: Unfortunately the second code block here is invalid - `Error: Missing key/value separator
│ 
│   on vars.tf line 43, in locals:
│   43:     k => { k => id }
│ 
│ Expected an equals sign ("=") to mark the beginning of the attribute value.`

Comment: Oh yes, indeed I accidentally wrote `=>` instead of `=`. I'll correct it.

Comment: This doesn't give the desired result either though :(

Comment: terraform console
> local.account_maps
tomap({
  "first_account" = {
    "k" = "111111111"
  }
  "fourth_account" = {
    "k" = "444444444"
  }
  "second_account" = {
    "k" = "222222222"
  }
  "third_account" = {
    "k" = "333333333"
  }
})

Comment: Ahh yes, again I was too hasty. Sorry I wasn't able to test these edits before posting them, since I no longer had the original configuration I was testing against. I think my latest update should work: placing the `k` in parentheses will tell Terraform that we want to evaluate the variable `k`, rather than use the literal key name `"k"`.

Comment: Thanks, this works and is certainly more graceful and legible than my solution! Two things -  the `tomap()` nesting appears to be unneeded; The configuration given in the question is 'complete', i.e. sufficient to run `terraform console` against and confirm result.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but could be helpful:

```
locals {
  accounts = merge(var.aws_accounts["first_ou"], var.aws_accounts["second_ou"])
}
```

If you need to do this in a more dynamic way:

```
locals {
  accounts = zipmap(
    flatten([for item in var.aws_accounts : keys(item)]), 
    flatten([for item in var.aws_accounts : values(item)])
  )
}
```

Now you can access each account with `local.accounts["first_account"]` etc.

Comment: The problem with that is that it isn't procedural, it's a static list of maps to merge and any changes will have to be updated in two different places

Comment: You could use something like `locals {
  accounts = zipmap(flatten([for item in var.aws_accounts : keys(item)]), flatten([for item in var.aws_accounts : values(item)]))
}` to be a bit more dynamic, I reckon.

Comment: Thanks for the update. this does give me a flattened list, unfortunately it's still not quite what I'm after. What I'd really like to be able to get 

    local.single_accounts
        {
          "first_account" = {
          first_account  = "111111111"
          } 
        ...etc

Answer (score 1):

OK So with help from [Martin Atkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281848/martin-atkins) and [Bryan Heden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3546408/bryan-heden) I have found an answer to this. It isn't exactly pretty but it does work:

```
variable "aws_accounts" {
  type = map(map(any))
  default = {
    first_ou = {
      first_account  = "111111111"
      second_account = "222222222"
    }
    second_ou = {
      third_account  = "333333333"
      fourth_account = "444444444"
    }
  }
}

locals {
  # gives single map from nested map
  account_ids = merge(values(var.aws_accounts)...)
  #   gives separate structured map for each key
  single_accounts_maps = {
    for account, id in local.account_ids :
    account => {
      account = account
      id      = id
    }
  }
  #   gives map where values = keys plus values
  single_accounts_maps_joined = zipmap(
    flatten([for item in var.aws_accounts : keys(item)]),
    [for item in local.single_accounts_maps :
    join(" = ", values(item))]
  )

  # gives nested map by key = {key = "value"}
  single_accounts_maps_keys_values = {
    for item in local.single_accounts_maps_joined :
    (split(" = ", item)[0]) => {
      (split(" = ", item)[0]) = (split(" = ", item)[1])
    }
  }
}
```

Output that I wanted:

```
terraform console
> local.single_accounts_maps_keys_values
{
  "first_account" = {
    "first_account" = "111111111"
  }
  "fourth_account" = {
    "fourth_account" = "444444444"
  }
  "second_account" = {
    "second_account" = "222222222"
  }
  "third_account" = {
    "third_account" = "333333333"
  }
}
```

After the discussion with [Martin Atkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281848/martin-atkins) and his subsequent edits below, I am recommending his answer instead as simpler, more legible and more graceful, although the `tomap()` nesting appears to be unneeded, i.e. do

```
locals {
  account_ids = merge(values(var.aws_accounts)...)
  account_maps = {
    for k, id in local.account_ids :
    k => { (k) = id }
  }
}
```